# Rectangle function and integration

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, rectangles

There are given:

$$\mbox{rect}(f/2a)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, & -a<f<a\\ 
0,5 &\begin{vmatrix}
f
\end{vmatrix}=a \\ 
 0& \begin{vmatrix}
f
\end{vmatrix}>a
\end{matrix}\right.$$

$V(f,t)$

**and I should find:**

$$\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}V(f,t) \cdot \mbox{rect}(f/2a) e^{j \pi f t}$$

I have started my solution with:
$$\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}V(f,t)\cdot \mbox{rect}(f/2a) e^{j \pi f t}=\int_{a}^{-a}V(f,t) e^{j \pi f t}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: What is the question? Your step is correct, given the definition of rect, except that the limits of integration are reversed.

Comment: @Chrystomath  I am not sure in the changing the interval of integration with such rect function.

Comment: @Chrystomath Is my last equation correct?

Comment: What are you integrating against exactly? $t$ or $f$?